# Strange WiFi symbol

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, cyberghost

This network with a strange symbol appeared in my available networks list:

[image: Screenshot]

I use CyberGhost VPN regularly but this network has never appeared before. I'm already connected to my WiFi and I don't have any LAN connections going in.

Searching in Google is giving me no results so I don't think it is some functionality of CyberGhost. I think it appeared right after I had some connectivity issues which were fixed after I restarted my modem.

Can someone tell me what this is about? It is the first time I've seen a network with that symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a "WiFi symbol". This is how Windows shows VPN connections; IKEv2 is a common protocol for establishing IPSec VPNs.

More specifically, this area lists connections made using Windows' built-in RRAS feature (PPTP VPNs, dial-up connections, in some cases 3G/4G) – as opposed to those which are implemented using the third-party TAP virtual adapter and managed completely by their own software.

So if you started seeing this item recently, it means CyberGhost have decided to switch over from a custom TAP-based VPN client to using the Windows built-in one.

Comment: But why is it there even after I close all cyberghost applications and services through task manager?

Comment: Because it's permanently configured -- much like manually added connections -- and its presence in the list is not related at all to whether the app is running. Note how the button says "Connect" and not "Disconnect".